Storage drives (USB Flash drives and system drives) can't be partitioned to use full labelled capacity
I have a box of USB's that I've used as installation media for various operating systems over the years, and have noticed, especially in a 256GB Kingston drive I was using for Ventoy that after reformatting, it has lost 25GB of maximum capacity. I looked at other drives and have found that most of my drives have lost about 10% capacity in nearly every drive I own. What's the deal with this? Is there any way I can recover this lost space?
